# Easy and quick way of getting raw data of jpeg image in Java?

Tags: java, image

I am using [this phone app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5wYXMud2ViY2FtIl0) as eyes for an application I'm writing on PC. The webcam app allows me to download instant shots in jpeg format. I need to do image processing of those shots and in order to do that I would like to get my hands on the raw data arrays - namely the matrix of pixels describing the image. How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to do

`ImageIO.read(new File("Image.jpeg"))`

to get the `BufferedImage`.  Using the `BufferedImage` you can use `getRGB(int x, int y)` or `getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)` for better performance.  Additionally, `getRaster()` is an option, which I've found to be the fastest (a little more effort though).

For setting pixels, similar `setRGB` methods exist.

Edit:  `ImageIO` is `javax.​imageio.​ImageIO`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best point to start is by reading a few words about image format specifications. Those should explain how the data is stored for different formats. With that knowledge you can write yourself a parser if you really feel like.

But think before: jpeg is not simply a raster  matrix of pixels as for example a bitmap image.

Most likely you will end up using an image processing library instead of working on the raw data yourself. That approach is much more convenient and less error prone.